# Query to get oldest date into a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables that look like this:

Table1

```
Column1
A
B
C
```

Table2

```
column1 Id1 Id2
A       2   100
A       3   101
B       2   100
B       3   101
C       2   100
```

Table3

```
Id2 Date     Item  Status
100 10/20/17  A1     A
101 10/21/17  A1     A
100 11/22/17  A2     I
101 11/23/17  A2     A
```

My query looks like this:

```
Select 
    Date, *
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON
T1.Column1 = T2.Column2
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON
T2.Id2 = T3.Id2
```

I would like to return the oldest date on table 3 where the status is A into the date column in my query.

I was able to return the oldest date with this query but can't integrate this into my query with joins.

```
 SELECT 
      MIN(DATE) 
 FROM Table3
 WHERE Id2 IN (100,101)
 AND STATUS = 'A'
 group by Id2, ITEM
```

How can I get the oldest date into the query that uses the join clauses?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. Given your sample data what do you want as output?

Comment: Your query looks fundamentally flawed. Your join conditions of `T1.Column1 = T2.Column2` and `T2.Id2 = T3.Id3` because they refer to columns that don't exist (`T2.Column2` and `T3.Id3`, respectively). Did you really mean to use `T1.Column1 = T2.Column1` and `T2.Id2 = T3.Id2`?

Comment: "I would like to return the oldest date on table 3 where the status is A into the date column in my query." -- does this mean that you simply wish to return the oldest date out of the rows that have status A? Why are the tables apart from Table3 necessary?

Comment: No one can help you if we don't know what you want.  Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to approach what I believe that you're trying to do.

I'd say the easiest would be to simplify your search parameters with a subquery of Table 3.

```
select *  from table2 t2
LEFT JOIN 
(Select Id2, Item, max(Date)from Table 3
WHERE Status = 'A'
GROUP BY Id2, Item)a ON t2.Id2 = a.Id2;
```

The subquery does the filtering and then a quick join to table 2 would get all your data.